# Operate or clone phone with broken screen

Tags: broken-screen, remote-control

I have an Oppo with a broken screen.  The Phone Link program from Microsoft is working, so I can do a few things (like controlling music play).

I would like to do a few operations like pressing approve buttons, or clone the whole phone.

I have a new phone, and on startup I start the cloning process, but I have to do something on the old phone.

Comment: What is the Android version and model? Can you elaborate broken screen? Is the screen totally unfunctional or it it just black and the touch screen is working? You can buy a USB hub and a USB type C to HDMI. Connect a USB mouse and HDMI to a monitor. Since this is a hardware problem there's nothing much you can do.